# Declare php array as javascript array situation

Tags: php, arrays

I was unable to find an answer to this situation that I have stumbled uppon this morning. I have declared some php variables as I usually do in javascript (by mistake). I was surprised that the code actually worked. I have tested it under Linux and it works fine. Under WAMP on Windows does not work.

**The code:**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$phones = [];

var_dump($phones);

?>
```

**Result in Linux:**

```
array(0) {
}
```

**Result in Windows:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in D:\wamp\www\test.php on line 7
```

**Question:** Is this a valid declaration of an array in php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP 5.4.0 offers a wide range of new features: [Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Short array syntax has been added,

e.g.

```
$a = [1, 2, 3, 4]; or $a = ['one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'four' => 4];
```

Above syntax is not supported below versions than 5.4.0. According to my understanding You might be running different versions of PHP in Linux & Windows. Use `phpinfo()` to check the PHP versions.

Comment: I have accepted your question because it had the link, even though `@Ardy Dedase` had answered first.

Answer (score 6):

The `[]` syntax is valid only in **PHP 5.4 or newer**, check your PHP version on windows.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the PHP Version on both your Linux and Windows machines.

I suspect that your Linux has PHP 5.4+ and Windows has PHP 5.3.x or lower.

I suggest you use `array()` instead of the short array syntax `[]` which is only valid in 5.4.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly like that.